# How do I make my Homebrew installation of Ruby the default over the macOS pre-installed version?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

After installing Homebrew and updating ruby to the latest version

```
brew upgrade ruby
```

when I run

```
which ruby
```

it still defaults to the pre-installed OSX version at

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

How do I change the default to my Homebrew installation?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`? You've to make sure the folder with your homebrew ruby installation comes before `/usr/bin` folder. OS picks the executable which is found first (according to the order of your $PATH variable)

Comment: I installed homebrew in /usr/local. echo $PATH returns /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Can you verify `ls /usr/local/bin/ruby` prints a present file. I'm not on OSX, see [this question on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are/580611#580611), that may help

Comment: This is what I get when I run that ls: /usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Comment: I suggest you use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) (or rbenv) instead of changing the system default.

Comment: Exactly what Amadan said: don't use brew to install Ruby, use a Ruby manager like RVM or rbenv or asdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install ruby
```

This will install the latest version of ruby, now you want to set it as default use for example in my case:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

this will set it as default in the profile
now you can check the version of ruby

```
ruby -v
```